# How to generate unique numeric short ID in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, database, algorithm

How to generate unique numeric short ID in nodejs?

I need to give each of my transaction one of these numeric short id

There can be millions of transactions

Comment: Is there any particular reason they need to be short and numeric only? what about alphanumeric? Most implementations use alphanumeric IDing especially when you'll have millions of entries. Also, what database are you using? Most DBs handle this automatically out of the box on transaction inserts.

Comment: sorry this numeric id is a separate id for human customer to read and pass around, will certainly have a long uuid for database, just need one more readable one

Comment: Then thats not possible with just numeric id.. Think about it.. you're getting millions of transactions. The length of the ids will increase as your transactions increase because you need to match a number to the transaction. And unless your data is indexed in the same table, you cannot ensure uniqueness. Best to use alphanumeric like https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid

Answer (score 6):

I have written an npm package named custom-id to solve that problem. You can tailor your custom-id as you like. If you want it numeric, you can do this. It can generate alphanumeric value too. You are concerned about the readability. That's why the plugin is written. It is built for both human and machine. We use familiar letters (from given name & email) in our randomly generated ID. People can easily recognize those familiar letters as they use it every time, every day, every moment. You can randomly generate IDs with uuid or nanoid, but these are not generated for human. These are for the machine. But this library is for both of them.

You can download this package from here - [custom-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-id)

```
npm i custom-id
```

You can generate an ID instantly by giving an empty object as the argument.

```
var customId = require("custom-id");

customId({}); // Voila... A random 8 character string will be generated automatically
```

The custom ID will be generated in this format -

✌✌** 2 Number + 2 Letter + 2 Number + 2 Letter = 8 characters ** ✌✌

All those number and letter will be generated randomly. We use cryptography to generate ids (if available).

[image]

You can read about the detailed documentation from here - [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-id)

But in your case, you just want a number, which is human readable, intuitive & unique. The code will be like -

```
var customId = require("custom-id")
customId({
  name: "123456",
  email: "78910"
});
// Random Result - "20111070" or "11435189" or "64656618"
```

You should look into that number. This is just a number but easy on the eye and easy to remember. This random id generator will not create a number like - 24359625! Thanks to its unique but very simple algorithm. That's why I suggest you use it.

Comment: How does this library ensure uniqueness of a short numeric id when one has millions of transactions? Not even considering collisions, you would run out of numbers by the time you hit 10 - 100 million transactions (if we have to keep the numbers short). So either 1. You have a non-unique numeric code that is cross-checked with a unique DB id because you will definitely get collisions, 2. You use alphanumeric to ensure uniqueness for a short id. or 3. Have an increasing possibly long numeric id. You can't have both a short and unique numeric id. So this doesn't solve the original problem.

Comment: There is no solution to the original problem. It's simple probability math. Use cases of this plugin and short human-readable unique ids are -  OTP(one-time-password), transaction ID, activation code, SMS code, Invitation key, React component key, Database random ID! You shouldn't expect 100 million ids in any of the cases. This solution will nicely work for a few million random ids. Obviously, you can use uuidv4 everywhere. But, human visible IDs should be nice and human-readable. It's all about generating human-readable ids for a few million cases!

Comment: A workaround for gaining both of the advantages can be - generate a uuidv4 and humans readable short id simultaneously. Then join and save it in the database. just like uuidv4_customId. Ex. 3e758628-fe49-4e84-b736-c27e68fbef3f_123456. When the user will see the id in the dashboard, get the id and split it by underscore, and show the unique portion only!

Answer (score 5):

`new Date().valueOf()` will give you simple number thats unique (unless you call it twice [in the same millisecond](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)).

Comment: Update: to solve the same millisecond problem, we can call the valueOf in setTimeout making it give more unique value every time you call it returns after 1ms
    setTimeout(()=>{
      const id = new Date().valueOf();
    })

Answer (score 3):

Try following function -

```js
function generate(n) {
  var add = 1,
    max = 12 - add;

  if (n > max) {
    return generate(max) + generate(n - max);
  }

  max = Math.pow(10, n + add);
  var min = max / 10; // Math.pow(10, n) basically 
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

  return ("" + number).substring(add);
}

console.log(`id with 6 digits - ${generate(6)}`);
console.log(`id with 7 digits - ${generate(7)}`);
console.log(`id with 8 digits - ${generate(8)}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Best to go with alphanumeric id. They are still readable, can be quite short and you are generally ensured of uniqueness across multiple tables. My recommendation would be the shortid node library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid

From their docs:

> ShortId creates amazingly short non-sequential url-friendly unique
>   ids. Perfect for url shorteners, MongoDB and Redis ids, and any other
>   id users might see.
>
> By default 7-14 url-friendly characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _- Supports
>   cluster (automatically), custom seeds, custom alphabet. Can generate
>   any number of ids without duplicates, even millions per day. Perfect
>   for games, especially if you are concerned about cheating so you don't
>   want an easily guessable id. Apps can be restarted any number of times
>   without any chance of repeating an id. Popular replacement for Mongo
>   ID/Mongoose ID. Works in Node, io.js, and web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use shortid package.
install package:

```
npm -i shortid
```

then you can use in code like this

```
  var shortid = require("shortid");
  id = shortid.generate();
```

Comment: But the question wants only numeric values. this package returns random characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package: https://npmjs.com/package/nodejs-unique-numeric-id-generator
It's a time-based Numeric ID generator and thus will always give a new id.

- It will generate a unique numeric id of length 6 by default.
- You can increase or decrease the length of output with minor changes in the library. Fell free to do it.

```nodejs
var nodejsUniqueNumericIdGenerator = require("nodejs-unique-numeric-id-generator")
nodejsUniqueNumericIdGenerator.generate(new Date().toJSON());
```

Answer (score 1):

just install [this packagge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-unique-numeric-id-generator) like

```
npm i nodejs-unique-numeric-id-generator

# yarn

yarn add nodejs-unique-numeric-id-generator
```

and add this in your node environmental

```
const ID = require("nodejs-unique-numeric-id-generator")

ID.generate(new Date().toJSON()); // output: "118626"

ID.generate(new Date().toJSON()); // output: "096984"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid or https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid. I personally prefer the second one.

Generating unique numbers is a much more complicated subject than most people think. Using timestamps, for example, might "work" in some cases, but create a security concern. They are too easy to guess. Please, for your own sake, take a look at the readme of the two libraries I mentioned before jumping to to simple "solution".